# Facebook Graph API Always Return Same Share Count

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to get share count of URLS but API always return same count for different URLS.

```
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://line.do/18-interesting-facts/kr
https://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://line.do/twitterda-paylasilan-en-onemli-13-fotograf/ks
```

Comment: Maybe they are using the same canonical `og:url` value, so that Facebook sees them as _one_ Open Graph object … no way to tell for us since the URLs you used seem not to be real ones. But the [debug tool](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug) will tell you exactly what’s up.

Comment: og:url meta tags are different http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://line.do/18-interesting-facts/kr or http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://line.do/twitterda-paylasilan-en-onemli-13-fotograf/ks

Answer (score 0):

Returning always same count because if page does not exists, site redirects to same 404 not found page.